# Grails 2.5.6 and SAML 2.0

Tags: grails-2.0, spring-saml

I use Grails 2.5.6 and I try to config saml with the plugin.

I can call the saml login but after my login I get a blanc site with redirect loop.

BuildConfig:

```
dependencies{   
    /*...*/
    compile('org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.2.RELEASE'){
        export = false
    }

    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.9.RELEASE')
}

plugins{
    /*...*/        
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"
    compile ":spring-security-saml:2.0.0"
}
```

Config:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = "de.streit.user.User"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = "de.streit.security.UserRole"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = "de.streit.security.Role"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'de.streit.security.Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authenticationFailureUrl = '/login/authfail?login_error=1'

// Define the authentication providers
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ["samlAuthenticationProvider"]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSwitchUserFilter = true

//SAML
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.metadata.providers = [idp: 'security/idp.xml']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.metadata.defaultIdp = 'idp'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.metadata.sp.defaults = [
    signingKey: 'estar',
    encryptionKey: 'estar',
    tlsKey: 'estar',
    alias     : 'http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal'
]
```

SP.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:Extensions>
        <idpdisco:DiscoveryResponse xmlns:idpdisco="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol"
                                    Location="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal/spring-security-saml/login/auth"/>
    </md:Extensions>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    MIIC9jCCArSgAwIBAgIETo67pDALBgcqhkjOOAQDBQAwXjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVUsxEDAOBgNVBAgT
                    B1Vua25vd24xDzANBgNVBAcTBmxvbmRvbjENMAsGA1UEChMEYnVyYjENMAsGA1UECxMEYnVyYjEO
                    MAwGA1UEAxMFZmVyb3owHhcNMTExMDA3MDg0MzE2WhcNMTIwMTA1MDg0MzE2WjBeMQswCQYDVQQG
                    EwJVSzEQMA4GA1UECBMHVW5rbm93bjEPMA0GA1UEBxMGbG9uZG9uMQ0wCwYDVQQKEwRidXJiMQ0w
                    CwYDVQQLEwRidXJiMQ4wDAYDVQQDEwVmZXJvejCCAbgwggEsBgcqhkjOOAQBMIIBHwKBgQD9f1OB
                    HXUSKVLfSpwu7OTn9hG3UjzvRADDHj+AtlEmaUVdQCJR+1k9jVj6v8X1ujD2y5tVbNeBO4AdNG/y
                    ZmC3a5lQpaSfn+gEexAiwk+7qdf+t8Yb+DtX58aophUPBPuD9tPFHsMCNVQTWhaRMvZ1864rYdcq
                    7/IiAxmd0UgBxwIVAJdgUI8VIwvMspK5gqLrhAvwWBz1AoGBAPfhoIXWmz3ey7yrXDa4V7l5lK+7
                    +jrqgvlXTAs9B4JnUVlXjrrUWU/mcQcQgYC0SRZxI+hMKBYTt88JMozIpuE8FnqLVHyNKOCjrh4r
                    s6Z1kW6jfwv6ITVi8ftiegEkO8yk8b6oUZCJqIPf4VrlnwaSi2ZegHtVJWQBTDv+z0kqA4GFAAKB
                    gQDKBDz1DFPPmmWp9n1FskJOev7CnnVFsKji1NLUDdifvS+uW+cnvnDfD3yPdxzUeknCrPTBRp+B
                    IvYUvLQ57LMIuLgKQ12RujGl0Oz9JbFMAHuBV2I/7ZykzGQPysSEqKCqG+kDc8VZ4AfIf/S8YnQk
                    xqdWQ5jLTIzXvcWd0WEYbDALBgcqhkjOOAQDBQADLwAwLAIUGP/oZpi79ZM1793XzZvnmrnmz5gC
                    FBm4bDN8h/0hAa83jaD8joLr098I
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    MIIC9jCCArSgAwIBAgIETo67pDALBgcqhkjOOAQDBQAwXjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVUsxEDAOBgNVBAgT
                    B1Vua25vd24xDzANBgNVBAcTBmxvbmRvbjENMAsGA1UEChMEYnVyYjENMAsGA1UECxMEYnVyYjEO
                    MAwGA1UEAxMFZmVyb3owHhcNMTExMDA3MDg0MzE2WhcNMTIwMTA1MDg0MzE2WjBeMQswCQYDVQQG
                    EwJVSzEQMA4GA1UECBMHVW5rbm93bjEPMA0GA1UEBxMGbG9uZG9uMQ0wCwYDVQQKEwRidXJiMQ0w
                    CwYDVQQLEwRidXJiMQ4wDAYDVQQDEwVmZXJvejCCAbgwggEsBgcqhkjOOAQBMIIBHwKBgQD9f1OB
                    HXUSKVLfSpwu7OTn9hG3UjzvRADDHj+AtlEmaUVdQCJR+1k9jVj6v8X1ujD2y5tVbNeBO4AdNG/y
                    ZmC3a5lQpaSfn+gEexAiwk+7qdf+t8Yb+DtX58aophUPBPuD9tPFHsMCNVQTWhaRMvZ1864rYdcq
                    7/IiAxmd0UgBxwIVAJdgUI8VIwvMspK5gqLrhAvwWBz1AoGBAPfhoIXWmz3ey7yrXDa4V7l5lK+7
                    +jrqgvlXTAs9B4JnUVlXjrrUWU/mcQcQgYC0SRZxI+hMKBYTt88JMozIpuE8FnqLVHyNKOCjrh4r
                    s6Z1kW6jfwv6ITVi8ftiegEkO8yk8b6oUZCJqIPf4VrlnwaSi2ZegHtVJWQBTDv+z0kqA4GFAAKB
                    gQDKBDz1DFPPmmWp9n1FskJOev7CnnVFsKji1NLUDdifvS+uW+cnvnDfD3yPdxzUeknCrPTBRp+B
                    IvYUvLQ57LMIuLgKQ12RujGl0Oz9JbFMAHuBV2I/7ZykzGQPysSEqKCqG+kDc8VZ4AfIf/S8YnQk
                    xqdWQ5jLTIzXvcWd0WEYbDALBgcqhkjOOAQDBQADLwAwLAIUGP/oZpi79ZM1793XzZvnmrnmz5gC
                    FBm4bDN8h/0hAa83jaD8joLr098I
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal/spring-security-saml/saml/SingleLogout"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal/spring-security-saml/saml/SingleLogout"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal/spring-security-saml/saml/SingleLogout"/>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal/spring-security-saml/saml/SSO" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal/spring-security-saml/saml/SSO" index="1" isDefault="false"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:PAOS" Location="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal/spring-security-saml/saml/SSO" index="2" isDefault="false"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
```

ipd.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://localhost:8080/Organisationsportal" cacheDuration="PT1440M" ID="XpK4KzotwbSFUKx.-NtBzfGDWti">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    MIICRTCCAa6gAwIBAgIGAR0gYMbwMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMGYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYD
                    VQQIEwJDTzEPMA0GA1UEBxMGRGVudmVyMQwwCgYDVQQKEwNEZXYxDTALBgNVBAsTBFBpbmcxHDAa
                    BgNVBAMTE0NvbmZpZyBTaWduaW5nIENlcnQwHhcNMDgxMDIxMTcwODEyWhcNMTMxMDIwMTcwODEy
                    WjBmMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECBMCQ08xDzANBgNVBAcTBkRlbnZlcjEMMAoGA1UEChMD
                    RGV2MQ0wCwYDVQQLEwRQaW5nMRwwGgYDVQQDExNDb25maWcgU2lnbmluZyBDZXJ0MIGfMA0GCSqG
                    SIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDQeOdW6I2hyXCQn0X/+8/BzLfRfdy1kN54lmVauYEpaPHQo7by
                    gPPRPUTDC3LgJGfk4NWkPaM+EOeLzuVw9rbD3gjfsex6hUElkvUzPqXqNN3sq/2hm+FJup+GakE9
                    WCoEP5sGvlJshH00a4MSzjGTBBqqjsXaWDZ7Sy9UAGw5BQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GB
                    AKSNMImzVs7L+tfortt7RBFMzc/JLE8qnulY32FrWA3ZLrD+08EBeIp1iwdJ8AGpii3SFV3oV3xu
                    92Qy2WqsBwj1erYdKW5mrfAbThkwL5N7jRsjJyXnIcx3IBvRD+O+LIDHck0cSgmN14ghleeslx0Q
                    15kyBdoxbv6pR0k4xOaF
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Location="*1" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Location="*1" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
```

*1 I removed this because it from my company..

I dont know what I'am missing.

I definde a bean in the resource for the userDetailsService but my spring didnt know that im logged in.

Thanks

Marvin Thör

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the problems I had.
I'll write my solution here.
**resources.groovy**

```
userDetailsService(OwnSpringSamlUserDetailsService){
 samlUserService = ref("samlUserService")//This is a own Service
   grailsApplication = ref("grailsApplication")
}

springSecurityService(OwnSpringSecurityService){
 config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
 authenticationTrustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
   grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
   passwordEncoder = ref('passwordEncoder')
   objectDefinitionSource = ref('objectDefinitionSource')
   userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
   userCache = ref('userCache')
}
```

The Problem here is that the saml spring override the getcurrentuser method.

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
dependencies{    
    //SAML
    compile('org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.2.RELEASE'){
        export = false
    }

    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.9.RELEASE')
}

plugins{
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"
    compile ":spring-security-saml:2.0.0"
}
```

The saml plugin used a old version of the spring core so I include the 3.2.9 Version to work with.

**Config.groovy**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.filterProcessesUrl = "/saml/SingleLogout"

// Define the authentication providers
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ["samlAuthenticationProvider"]

//SAML
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.metadata.sp.defaults = [
      alias : 'localhost:dev:YOUR-APPNAME',
      entityBaseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/YOUR-APPNAME'
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.metadata.url = "YOUR-METADATA-URL"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.metadata.providers = ['ping': 'security/idp.xml']
```

you have to set the alias for the sp.xml. For me urls as alias not working.

**UrlMapping.groovy**

```
//SAML
"/saml/logout"(controller: 'logout', action: 'index')
```

I used this urlmapping for the logout

For the sp.xml I used the generated xml but I changed the entityID to:
**localhost:dev:YOUR-APPNAME**

Comment: what is the YOUR-METADATA-URL ? Can you please share your sample app Github link @Marvin